# Escrever palavra sucessivas ate ao fim do ciclo

Tags: string, loop, ocaml

```
let palavra="1234567";;
let tamanho=String.length palavra;;
for i = 0 to 6 do
  print_string String.sub palavra i (tamanho-i);
  print_string "\n";
done;;
```

Tentei executar o respectivo codigo mas nao devolve o esperado.
Como faço para imprimir palavras sucessivas:

1234567

234567

34567

4567

Answer (score 0):

Apenas parênteses estão faltando.

```
# print_string String.sub palavra i (tamanho-i);;
Error: This function has type string -> unit
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

Você precisa de parênteses em torno do argumento de `print_string`.

```
let palavra="1234567";;
let tamanho=String.length palavra;;
for i = 0 to 6 do
  print_string (String.sub palavra i (tamanho-i));
  print_string "\n";
done;;
```

Em vez de `print_string "\n"`, é mais fácil usar `print_endline`.
Para tornar o código mais geral, use o comprimento como o terminal do ciclo.

```
for i = 0 to tamanho do
  print_endline (String.sub palavra i (tamanho-i));
done;;
```